# Getting 502 errors using SVN + Apache + Windows + HTTPS

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, https

As stated in the title, we are experiencing 502 / bad gateway/proxy errors in the following environment: SVN over HTTPS through Apache on Windows 2008 R2. These errors occur specifically when doing copies, merge operations or branching.

As an additional note, we are using LDAP for authentication.

We've read through numerous posts with similar issues, but haven't been able to resolve our solution. This post seems similar, but the solutions given do not resolve it for us: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479346/502-bad-gateway-with-nginx-apache-subversion-ssl-svn-copy

Perhaps we are placing the following line of code in the wrong place? Can anyone give direction on where that should go specifically?

> RequestHeader edit Destination ^https http early

Comment: Could you post any errors from apache's error log?

Comment: Just regular 502 errors - nothing helpful otherwise. I think we're putting the "REquestHeader edit..." entry in the wrong place I just can't figure out where it belongs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article quoted and linked below should set you on the right track:

> ... except for commits which copy or
>   move files/directories. This is
>   because the DAV requests COPY and MOVE
>   use the header Destination to contain
>   the full target path of the operation.
>
> If you are using Apache 2.0 or 2.2 for
>   your subversion server, you need to
>   backport mod_headers from the HEAD
>   revision of Apache. Fortunately this
>   is not very difficult for this
>   particular module.

[Subversion behind an Apache Reverse Proxy](https://web.archive.org/web/20140605093440/http://silmor.de/proxysvn.php) (includes instructions to resolve issue and a mod_rewrite workaround which looks promising)

Comment: Looks very promising. We will try in the next day or so and check back to this thread to update.